# How to use arduino IDE to compile .s files

Tags: arduino-ide, assembly

Hi I'm new to arduino and im using it to learn assembly for my computer hardware 101 class, I read online that I can make the IDE accept .s files and compile them to the board but I dont know how to do this (something about editing the source code and recompiling the IDE?).

Could I get a step by step walk through? Assuming it's relatively simple, or just a link to some relevant documentation that's not a literal reference manual :-).

**EDIT**
As terrible as it is,I'm working from a macbook pro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IDE should be able to accept `.S` files (not `.s` - the difference is very important: `.S` will be preprocessed, `.s` won't).

Just create a new sketch, and create a new tab called `whatever.S` (obviously rename the `whatever` to whatever you want to call it.

Then in the main sketch `.ino` file put something like:

```
extern "C" void myAssemblyMain();

void setup() {
    myAssemblyMain();
}
void loop() {
}
```

That will then call the function `myAssemblyMain:` in your assembly file and not much else.

(Note: I haven't tested this since I don't use the Arduino IDE).

Comment: Note that, if you do not rely on the initializations done by the Arduino core library, you can write `main()` instead of `setup()` and `loop()`. You may also write `main()` in assembly and put something else in the .ino file: a dummy unused function, or maybe nothing at all (though I don't know if the IDE will accept an empty .ino).